# python TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment python

Tags: python

this issue appear when I put promedios[x] = float(punteos / 3), if suppose to x is in for outside have a int value like possition. I modified the code with the new changes

```
def alumno(nombre, apellido):
  print('Nombre: ', nombre, 'Apellido: ', apellido)

def promedio(a,b,c):
  promedio1 = int(a+b+c)/3
  #return promedio1
  print(promedio1)

nombre = input('ingrese nombre: ')
apellido = input('ingrese apellido: ')

alumno(nombre,apellido)
print()

#promedio(1,2,3)


print('Ingrese los punteos de las Materias:')
punteo = 0
materias = 5
for x in range(0, materias):
  punteos = 0
  notas = 3
  promedio1 = 0
  promedios = []
  xx = 1
  for y in range(0, notas):
    punteo = int(input("Ingrese punteo de la Materia "+str(x+1)+" punteo "+str(y+1)+": "))
    punteos = int(punteos + punteo)
    promedio1 = float(punteos/3)
    promedios.append(promedio1)
  print('El promedio de la materia ',x+1,' es ',promedio1)
  print(promedios[x])
```

Comment: `promedios = 0`. What is `promedios[x]` meant to mean?

Comment: I want to promedios be a array, but store the value of first for

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have done `promedios = 0` and no longer modify the variable `promedios` before the line of code `promedios[x] = float(punteos / 3)`, `promedios` is an `int` at that line.

However, doing `promedios[x] = ...` calls the `__setitem__` method of variable `promedios`, which is of type `int` and of course does not support such item assignment.

Types like `list`, `dict` support item assignment, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with an empty list:

```
promedios = []
```

And then append to it:

```
promedios.append(float(punteos / 3))
```

Comment: why in my lasts sentences show me this? promedio1 = float(punteos/3)
    promedios.append(promedio1)
  print('El promedio de la materia ',x+1,' es ',promedio1)
  print(promedios[x]). El promedio de la materia  1  es  1.0
0.3333333333333333, sorry for my english

Comment: Why shouldn't it be that?

Comment: print(promedio1( and print(promedios[x]) should be 1 and 1, the same result, because its like promedios[] was dividing the promedio1